# How can I convert Table to new rows and combine multiplie columns into one?

Tags: excel, powerbi

I have got stuck on this for a while, i know how to make rows with columns but not how to create a combo of more into one. =)
This is the data

```
Id  M1  M1Comments  M2  M2Comments  M3  M3Comments
1   Yes "Blabla"    Yes "Blabla"    No  "Blabla"
2   Yes "Blabla"    No  "Blabla"    No  "Blabla"
3   No  "Blabla"    No  "Blabla"    No  "Blabla"
```

And the end result should look like this

```
Id  M   Value   Comments
1   M1  Yes "Blabla"
1   M2  Yes "Blabla"
1   M2  No  "Blabla"
2   M1  Yes "Blabla"
2   M2  No  "Blabla"
2   M3  No  "Blabla"
3   M1  No  "Blabla"
3   M2  No  "Blabla"
3   M3  No  "Blabla"
```

Comment: From your original 7 columns, you can create a new row with columns 1;"M1";2;4 ("M1" is fixed text!) and 2;"M2";4;5 and 3;"M3";6;7     The result should be your output. (it only might needs sorting)

Comment: You can do it in Power Query Editor using Unpivot option.

Answer (score 2):

1. Unpivot everything except `Id`.
2. Split the Attribute column.
3. Pivot on the second column from the split.
4. Rename columns as desired.

```
let
    Source = < Your Data Soucre Here >,
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Id"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Split Column by Position" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 2}, false), {"M", "Comment"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Split Column by Position", List.Distinct(#"Split Column by Position"[Comment]), "Comment", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{{"", "Value"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: I tryed to follow the 4 steps. 1. Easy 2. Split the column by position 0,2... The result is Headers ( Id,Attrebute,Value ) like Id 1 become 6 rows. Row 1 1,M1,Yes and Row2 1,M1Comments,"Blablabla". I mark the Attribute Column and press split "by numbers of characters" and enter 2 and press Once as far left as possible. This make a new Column called Attrubute2, Every other is now empty and the other say Comments. Now I stand still

Comment: Pivot the Attribute2 column with Value as the values column (choose don't aggregate from the advanced options).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below **Advance Editor** code for table to achieve your desired output-

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUYpMLQaSyfm5ual5JQqGCrlYBY2AXL98VDFjpVidaCUjDOVGEDNQlBthMcIIZoQxuowxFhOMsZhgDDYhFgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Id = _t, M1 = _t, M1Comments = _t, M2 = _t, M2Comments = _t, M3 = _t, M3Comments = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Id", Int64.Type}, {"M1", type text}, {"M1Comments", type text}, {"M2", type text}, {"M2Comments", type text}, {"M3", type text}, {"M3Comments", type text}}),
    
    // New steps started from here
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Id"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Columns", "Custom", each if Text.End([Attribute],8) = "Comments" then [Value] else null),
    #"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Up", each not Text.Contains([Attribute], "Comments")),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Attribute", "M"}, {"Custom", "Comments"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Input-

[image]

Output-

[image]

**Condition**
Comments column name has to contain text **Comments**

Comment: Hi im glad for the code, but to be able to apply this in more projekts i need more step by step or, Images

Comment: This should work for more column when the comments column name following the above naming format.